# Get parameter from url in ASP.net core 2.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, knockout.js, asp.net-identity

I have the following method:

[image: Method]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnVpZ.png)

This method sends a token to the email to be able to recover the password which works correctly. Now, I created the following function with JavaScript to retrieve the parameter that I have in the URL,

[image]

This way I can get the parameter I have in the URL, which is the following:

```
https://localhost:5001/AdminUsers/ResetPassword?token=CfDJ8KA%2FkcFChM9Bp%2F8oQHF0OBo113jwJ7upCuf31%2FnOQ%2BWnPS8Dl6kvAMvhRJ1wWsJEKvckfViPbczsNs09kmnUXcMtY7yxnePjossD3LwfVrJo1EXCRk%2B%2FyluiExuLziOmrtVrdMbVKUvn0oBti5vsF%2FOGs2yWdUR%2BFHrGQKe4ioVVnT9m6np0%2FhFjkZawi%2BvHqjM7ayP5cR5VQWTxrhjsvEzJctqsUhEudVXe53JAvmMW%2BYtGFKSSWwOTcp5RFDE9Hw%3D%3D
```

But at the moment I am trying to change the password with that token, it indicates to me that the token is invalid, but the token is the same as the one in the URL, as shown in the following images:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2zj6.png)

[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouJsX.png)

What I am doing is the following through the action URL:

- I send the token, to be able to change the password
- After I return a view with a form in which the user will have to enter the user and the password
- I receive the user and password through an Ajax call, since I am using Knockout.js framework

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: welcome! please post your code, not as an image but as text.

Answer (score 0):

In the URL, the value was URL encoded, so that it could be validly used in the URL. When provided via the URL, the framework is smart enough to decode the value before binding it to the appropriate action param. However, when you then send it via the request body, that no longer occurs. The value is set on your model as-is, and yeah, it's not going to match the actual token, because they're very much different strings.

Long and short, you either need to URL decode the value on the client-side before making the AJAX request or URL decode it server-side before you actually attempt to use the token. On the client side you can use: `decodeURIComponent(value)`. Server-side, you'd need to use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value)`.

Comment: I did not understand very well how I am going to do it the decodeURIComponent (value) I am going to put it in the model where I am receiving the token, and the HttpUtility.UrlDecode (value) in the controller I am using to reset the password

Comment: It's an either/or thing. The point is that you need to decode the value somewhere. That could be client side before you send the request or server side before you make the call that uses it. It doesn't matter.

Comment: I would stay like this then IdentityResult result = await _userHelper.ResetPasswordAsync (myUser, HttpUtility.UrlDecode (login.Token), login.Password); 
, but the decodeURIComponent (value) does not know where to place it

Comment: edit the question using HttpUtility.UrlEncode and HttpUtility.UrlDeEncode and it throws me the same invalid token error